# Using two overloads of a function with params and a variable of the same type as params

Tags: c#, overloading, parameters

I was writing a class with two diffrent constructor overloads:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(params string[] Files)
    {

    }
    public MyClass(string Path, params string[] Files)
    {

    }
}
```

After I wrote it, my code got me confused that how should I know that if the variable `Path` is given as argument or not. 
There is no error in program but I'm wondering for example if I run the following code, how to understand that `Path` is given or not?

```
MyClass x = new Myclass("a","b","c");
```

it can be either

```
Path = "a";
Files = string[]{"b","c"};
```

or just

```
Files = string[]{"a", "b", "c"};
```

Comment: If it's confusing, best not to code your constructors that way.

Comment: well what would you suggest?

Comment: Alternatives: Use either an explicit array instead of `params` (e.g. `new MyClass("a", new[] {"b", "c"})` or make your constructor private and use two shared methods with different names to create instances.

Comment: Personally, I would redesign it using @Henzi's 2nd suggestion.  It will remove all confusion.  And when he said *shared* methods, I guess he meant *static* methods in C# terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using named parameters:

> MyFunction(parameter1: value1, parameter2: value2);